# Calling derived template class method from base non-template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization

I'm trying to create the following flow:

Having a 'Base' class, with no params or functionality, just so i can hold
Base pointers in a method.

Its derived class, is a template, which implements operator() on given template argument object type.

I'm trying, by using a pointer to base class, call the derived class operator(), in run-time.

I've tried implementing it using CRTP
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)
But that doesn't seem to work the-other-way-around - when the derived class is a class template.

Here is my code:

```
class Base {};

template<typename Ref_Obj, typename Obj_Type>
class Derived : public Base {
    private:
        typedef bool (Ref_Obj::*Func_p)(Obj_Type) const;
        Func_p m_func;
        const Ref_Obj& m_db;

    public:
        Derived<Ref_Obj, Obj_Type>(const Ref_Obj& db, Func_p func): m_db(base), m_func(filter) {}

        inline bool operator()(const Obj_Type& obj) const {
            return (m_db.*m_func)(obj);
        }
}
```

Now, usage is in another class template, that contains vector of Base class pointers, as follows, and have its own operator() :

```
template<typename Obj_Type2> /* Upon usage, Obj_Type2 is the same as Obj_Type, this is just to differ the two in the code here */
class BlaBla {
    private:
        std::vector<const Base *> m_vec;

    public:
        /* relevant constructors ... */

        inline bool operator()(const Obj_Type2 &obj) const {
            for(std::vector<const Base *>::const_iterator it = m_vec.begin(); it != m_vec.end(); ++it) {

                /*** This is the problematic line V ***/
                if( (*it).operator()(obj) ) { /* DO SOMETHING */ }                    
        }
}
```

Of course the compiler is complaining that there is no matching function to call for in the problematic line that is marked in the code below, but i can't figure out a way to do the relevant call.

**1st Solution** that came to mind, is to create a **virtual operator()(...)**, with a **specific object type e.g. virtual operator()(const uint32_t &obj)** in Base class, which works, but my intention is that operator()(...) will receive a variety of object types, and stating a virtual method for each of them is not elegant and seems to break all the template concept i want to implement here.

**2nd Solution** that came to mind, is somehow passing **Ref_Obj** and **Obj_Type** typenames to Base class, to be used in sort of interface method, that will use static_cast to call the appropriate Derived operator (As in CRTP) - But that doesn't seem to work because Derived class is a class template, and also BlaBla class doesn't directly know **Ref_Obj** typename.

Is there any other way to make the appropriate call to Deriver operator()

Comment: What is the spectrum of types you want to pass to derived `operator()`? If they all share some common ancestor `TypeBase`, you can declare protected `virtual bool Base::operator()(TypeBase&)` and public `template<T> bool Base::operator()(T&)` implemented in terms of virtual one, overridden in derived classes.

Comment: They don't share a common ancestor, as they can be class pointers, primitive types, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear clean way to do this. The fundamental problem is that there is no such thing as a virtual template method.

The cleanest way I can think of doing this that implements complete type erasure is with a dynamic cast, and a virtual method:

```
class Base {
public:

    virtual bool operator()(const Base &) const=0;
};

template<typename Ref_Obj, typename Obj_Type>
class Derived : public Base {
    private:
        typedef bool (Ref_Obj::*Func_p)(Obj_Type) const;
        Func_p m_func;
        const Ref_Obj& m_db;

    public:
        Derived<Ref_Obj, Obj_Type>(const Ref_Obj& db, Func_p func): m_db(base), m_func(filter) {}

        inline bool operator()(const Base& obj) const override {
            const Obj_Type *derived_obj=dynamic_cast<const Obj_Type *>(&obj);

            if (!derived_obj)
            {
                  throw; // Or maybe return false, or something...
            }
            return (m_db.*m_func)(*derived_obj);
        }
};
```

`Obj_Type` must also be derived from `Base`. This gets the job done at runtime, but there is no compile-time type-checking.

The other approach is to bite the bullet, and forego 100% type erasure:

```
template<typename Obj_Type>
class Base {
public:

    virtual bool operator()(const Obj_Type &) const=0;
};

template<typename Ref_Obj, typename Obj_Type>
class Derived : public Base<Obj_Type> {
    private:
        typedef bool (Ref_Obj::*Func_p)(Obj_Type) const;
        Func_p m_func;
        const Ref_Obj& m_db;

    public:
        Derived<Ref_Obj, Obj_Type>(const Ref_Obj& db, Func_p func): m_db(base), m_func(filter) {}

        inline bool operator()(const Obj_Type& obj) const override {
            return (m_db.*m_func)(obj);
        }
};
```

So, you can still abstract away `operator()` on some object to its pure interface, and define the details in the subclass.

Or, another alternative would be a combination of the two:

```
class SuperBase {
public:

    virtual bool operator()(const Base &) const=0;
};

template<typename Obj_Type>
class Base : public SuperBase {
public:

    virtual bool operator()(const Obj_Type &) const=0;

    bool operator()(const Base &obj) const override
    {
          // Do the dynamic cast check, and forward it to the other
          // operator().
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey, Making the base class a class template, will not make it impossible to declare a vector of _"Base *"_ in the  _"BlaBla"_ class, due to **incomplete type error** ??

Comment: One more question - All of your solutiond refer to changes in Base and Derived classes. Using those suggested changes, will help me in the manner of calling **operator()(const Obj_Type &obj)** of _Derived class_, from the **BlaBla** class, with a **Base * **? (which doesn't inherit or friends with the **Base or Derived** classes, just knows their definition)

Comment: Regarding the first suggested solution, i can't have **Obj_Type** derive from **Base class** , as Obj_Type can be practically any type - another class pointer, some primitive type, etc..

Comment: Sometimes you can't have what you want. C++ is what it is. That's how it works. You can't change how the language works; and one's class design and structure often needs to be adjusted in order to actually make it possible to implement, in the language. You can't change the C++ language itself.

Comment: Dear Sam, your second suggested solution did the trick, with minor adjustments to other relevant code pieces. Thank you